# Oracle Nesting With Clauses

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

I have a need to split one record into 2 when they meet a certain criteria and I have difficulty joining them together after splitting them up.
I have this table:

[image]

For meetings that a day, I need to split them up into 2 sessions, one in the morning and one in the afternoon. In this example, I need to split Test 2 into 2 sessions AM and PM.

[image]

I have used this statement and it serves me well:

```
WITH DATA
AS 
  (SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN level=1 THEN 'AM'
      WHEN LEVEL=2 THEN 'PM'
    END "Session"
  FROM dual CONNECT BY level<3) 
SELECT "Meeting","From","EndTime","StartTime","Session" 
FROM "TEST", DATA
WHERE ("StartTime" < 12 AND "StartTime">=8) AND ( "EndTime"    >  12 AND "EndTime" <= 17)
```

However, when I attempted to combine the other meeting that last half day, I got the error below:

```
ORA-32034: unsupported use of WITH clause
32034. 00000 -  "unsupported use of WITH clause"
*Cause:    Inproper use of WITH clause because one of the following two reasons
           1. nesting of WITH clause within WITH clause not supported yet
           2. For a set query, WITH clause can't be specified for a branch.
           3. WITH clause can't sepecified within parentheses.
*Action:   correct query and retry
Error at Line: 56 Column: 1
```

This is the sql statement I used:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
SELECT "Meeting","From","EndTime","StartTime" ,
  CASE
    WHEN "StartTime" >= 8 AND "EndTime"    <= 12 THEN 'AM'
    WHEN "StartTime" >= 12 AND "EndTime"    <= 17 THEN 'PM'
    ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
  END "Session"
FROM "TEST"
WHERE ("StartTime" >= 8 AND "EndTime"      <= 12)
      OR 
      ("StartTime"    >= 12 AND "EndTime"      <= 17)
) HalfDay
UNION ALL
(
WITH DATA
AS 
  (SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN level=1 THEN 'AM'
      WHEN LEVEL=2 THEN 'PM'
    END "Session"
  FROM dual CONNECT BY level<3) 
SELECT "Meeting","From","EndTime","StartTime","Session" 
FROM "TEST", DATA
WHERE ("StartTime" < 12 AND "StartTime">=8) AND ( "EndTime"    >  12 AND "EndTime" <= 17) 
) FullDay
```

How do I fix this?
Please find attached the script to create the table and related data.

```
  CREATE TABLE "TEST" 
   (    "Meeting" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "From" DATE, 
    "StartTime" NUMBER, 
    "EndTime" NUMBER
   ) ;

Insert into TEST ("Meeting","From","StartTime","EndTime") values ('Test 1',to_date('06-JUL-15','DD-MON-RR'),12,17);
Insert into TEST ("Meeting","From","StartTime","EndTime") values ('Test 2',to_date('12-DEC-15','DD-MON-RR'),8,17);
```

My goal is getting this output

[image]

along with this one in 1 view

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not really nesting two with clauses, but you do nest one inside a union.

The `with` clause declares one or more subqueries and assigns them a name that can be used further down in the query, like a view.

So thats what you can do here as well. Move the entire `with` clause and the inline view it defines to the top. After that, the union part follows. After a little clean-up it would look like this:

```
WITH 
  DATA AS 
  (SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN level=1 THEN 'AM'
      WHEN LEVEL=2 THEN 'PM'
    END "Session"
  FROM dual CONNECT BY level < 3) 

SELECT "Meeting","From","EndTime","StartTime" ,
  CASE
    WHEN "StartTime" >= 8 AND "EndTime" <= 12 THEN 'AM'
    WHEN "StartTime" >= 12 AND "EndTime" <= 17 THEN 'PM'
    ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
  END "Session"
FROM "TEST"
WHERE ("StartTime" >= 8 AND "EndTime" <= 12)
      OR 
      ("StartTime" >= 12 AND "EndTime" <= 17)
UNION ALL
SELECT "Meeting", "From", "EndTime", "StartTime", "Session" 
FROM "TEST", DATA
WHERE 
  "StartTime" < 12 AND "StartTime" >= 8 AND 
  "EndTime" > 12 AND "EndTime" <= 17
```

The same query without `WITH`:

```
SELECT "Meeting","From","EndTime","StartTime" ,
  CASE
    WHEN "StartTime" >= 8 AND "EndTime" <= 12 THEN 'AM'
    WHEN "StartTime" >= 12 AND "EndTime" <= 17 THEN 'PM'
    ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
  END "Session"
FROM "TEST"
WHERE ("StartTime" >= 8 AND "EndTime" <= 12)
      OR 
      ("StartTime" >= 12 AND "EndTime" <= 17)
UNION ALL
SELECT "Meeting", "From", "EndTime", "StartTime", "Session" 
FROM 
  "TEST",   
  (SELECT
      CASE
        WHEN level=1 THEN 'AM'
        WHEN LEVEL=2 THEN 'PM'
      END "Session"
    FROM dual CONNECT BY level < 3)
WHERE 
  "StartTime" < 12 AND "StartTime" >= 8 AND 
  "EndTime" > 12 AND "EndTime" <= 17
```

Comment: Got sql command not properly ended... Even if it worked, moving using to the top alters the semantic of the sql. I only wanted to add AM and PM to the records that have 2 sessions.

Comment: It does not alter the semantics of the SQL. You can see `DATA` as a view used in the other part of the query, It could even be an actual view outside of your query. Alternatively, you could skip the entire `with` part and put the subselect in place where you use `DATA` now.

Comment: Moving the whole part sql part containing the using statement works! Thank you!

Comment: You are right! No need to use the with part. I am a bit fuzzy as to when I need to use with. Mind shedding some light on it for me?

Comment: I've added the same query with the DATA eliminated. The subquery is now embedded. I've got a feeling this query might be a little simpler by the way, but I don't really understand the intentions.

Answer (score 1):

A bit more compact solution using two subqueries (ommitning the union).
The first one for a mapping table, providing join either one to one or the split in two records.
The second subquery transform your date source adding the "Duration" key, which represents
the tree cases: AM only, PM only or both AM + PM
The rest is a simple join.

```
with join_helper as (
select 'AM' "Duration", 'AM'  "Session" from dual union all
select 'PM' "Duration", 'PM'  "Session" from dual union all
select 'AM-PM' "Duration", 'AM'  "Session" from dual union all
select 'AM-PM' "Duration", 'PM'  "Session" from dual),
session_duration as (
select test.*,
  CASE
    WHEN "StartTime" < 12 AND "EndTime"    >= 12 THEN 'AM-PM'
    WHEN "StartTime" < 12 THEN 'AM'
    WHEN "EndTime"   >= 12 THEN 'PM' 
  END "Duration"    
from test)
select a."Meeting", a."From",a."StartTime",a."EndTime",  b."Session" 
from session_duration a, join_helper b
where a."Duration" = b."Duration"  
;
```

You may find the logic less scattered in the query..

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT "Meeting","From","EndTime","StartTime" ,
  CASE
    WHEN "StartTime" >= 8 THEN 'AM'
  END "Session"
FROM "TEST"
union all
 SELECT "Meeting","From","EndTime","StartTime" ,
  CASE
    WHEN  "EndTime" <= 17 THEN 'PM'
  END "Session"
FROM "TEST"
where "StartTime" <12 AND "EndTime" <= 17 ;
```